# Base64 plugin not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

The plugin was working fine until recently I started facing problems with it, the code does not execute neither does it throw an error. I want to capture images from camera and send the `base64` string to the server, which was easy since I could directly get the `base64` of the captured image but then I used the native [crop](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/crop/) which returns the `URI` of the cropped image. So now I HAVE to get the `base64` of this image, but the `Base64` plugin isn't working anymore. Any workaround or help is really appreciated.
Code I used:

```
this.base64.encodeFile(filePath).then((base64File: string) => {
    console.log(base64File);    // Won't execute
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);  // Won't execute
});
```

Comment: Can you share any error messages with us? Are you sure the cropping succeed, can you check that again?

Comment: @StephanStrate: Yes, it succeeds as I am able to display the cropped image, however when I try to the convert the cropped image (using it's URI) to it's base64 using the above code, nothing happens. Sorry but there is no error message as you can check in my original post, none of the blocks gets executed.

Comment: Try `.catch` instead of `err` on your promise and make sure your code is executed.

Comment: using catch gives a syntax error in the above code.

Comment: `this.base64.encodeFile(filePath).then().catch(err => {console.log(err);});` Make sure you use this syntax

Comment: @StephanStrate: I tried your code, but the catch is not executed

Comment: No one can help you with this code snippet, we need more informations in order to help you. My guess is, that this code is not executed at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164604/discussion-between-tejas-k-and-stephan-strate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spent couple of hours on the same bug. It occurred that this plugin just stopped working (it's still beta version). I made some changes in my code and replaced Base64 plugin with File Plugin.

1. Add File plugin to app.module.ts imports.
2. Import and inject dependency in component/service constructor.

And then if you have filepath:

```
// split file path to directory and file name
let fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
let path = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

this.file.readAsDataURL(path, fileName)
.then(base64File => {
    console.log("here is encoded image ", base64File)
})
.catch(() => {
    console.log('Error reading file');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android, in the build.gradle(app) file, change target SDK to targetSdkVersion 30.

Then go to your AndroidManifest.xml and add this line android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in the application tag like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

try to apply this solution is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Base64 plugin is need install [Device](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device)

See the repo [phonegap-base64](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64/blob/master/www/Base64.js) line 11

```
if (device.platform == "Android")
```